# What is the best way to store Time Series in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, time-series

I want to store a large number of Time Series (time vs value) data points. I would prefer using MySQL for the same. Right now I am planning to store the time series as a Binary Blob in MySQL. Is this the best way, what would be the best approach.

Comment: Accept some answers to your previous questions, you'll be more likely to get a better response if you do.

Answer (score 2):

You should store your values as whatever type they are (int, boolean, char) and your times as either date, or int containing the UNIX timestamp, whatever fits your application better.

Comment: Wont this cause scaling issues? In my scenario, the number of rows will increase drastically.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to process the information in any way using mysql you should store it as a date type, numeric type .
The only scaling issue i see (if you only intend to store the information) is extra disk size.

Answer (score 0):

As both Tom and aeon said, you should store data in its native format in MySQL if you want to do anything with that data (-> process the data with SQL).

If, on the other end, you don't want to work on that data, but just store/retrieve it, then you are using MySQL just as a blob container where every blob is a mess/group of multiple time/data points, and it could not be the best tool for the job: that's what files are designed for.

You could investigate an hybrid approach where you possibly store the data non-structured, but you store timestamps as discrete values. In other words, a key/value store with your timestamps as keys. That should open up the possibility to work with [NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) solutions and maybe you could find out that they fit better (eg. think about running [map/reduce jobs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) directly on the db in a [Riak](http://wiki.basho.com/Riak.html) cluster)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your application, using the spatial data extensions of MySQL could be an option. You could then use spatial indexing to query the data fast. 
To represent a time series, the LineString class might be the most appropriate choice. It represents a sequence of tuples you could use to store time and value.
[Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gis-class-linestring.html) it says that "On a world map, LineString objects could represent rivers." 
Creating line strings is easy:

```
-- if you see a blob, use Convert( AsText(...) using 'utf8')
SELECT AsText(GeomFromText('LineString(1 1, 2 2, 3.5 3.9)'));
```

Some links to get started:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/spatial-extensions.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/populating-spatial-columns.html